# Asignar tamaño fijo a las columnas de una tabla HTML

Tags: html5, css3

Como puedo establecer un tamaño fijo a un `<td>` independientemente del contenido de las celdas, de modo que las columnas no pierdan su tamaño, por ejemplo:

```html
<table style="width:100%" border=1>
      <tr>
        <th style="width:15px"></th>
        <th style="width:50px">Clave</th>
        <th style="width:50px">Tópico</th> 
        <th style="width:50px">Descripcion</th>
        <th style="width:50px">Objetivo</th>
        <th style="width:50px">Justificación</th>
        <th style="width:50px">Área de estudio</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="width:15px;"></td>
        <td style="width:50px;">001</td>
        <td style="width:50px;">Cultura General.</td> 
        <td style="width:50px;">¿Alguna vez has puesto a prueba tu conocimiento sobre el mundo, la historia, las ciencias, el lenguaje y el arte? Tal vez no seas un sabelotodo ni un investigador que pasa sus días en un laboratorio con los ojos pegados a un microscopio, pero hay ciertos datos que deberías conocer para tener una noción del paso del hombre por la Tierra y la complejidad de sus acciones.</td>
        <td style="width:50px;">Medir la profundidad de tu cultura general.</td>
        <td style="width:50px;">Medir el conocimiento general de la Organización.</td>
        <td style="width:50px;">Cultura General.dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd</td>
      </tr>
        
    </table>
```

https://codepen.io/Chekame/pen/jBQwYK

En ese ejemplo, necesito que todas las columnas tengan el mismo ancho.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Añadiendo un ancho fijo  a su tabla y además la propiedad [table-layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout) , y luego asignar un ancho a los `td` , y `th` y [overflow-wrap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap) para controlar el contenido de estos.

```css
table{
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 250px;
}

th, td {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    width: 100px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<table border="2">
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>Clave</th>
    <th>Tópico</th> 
    <th>Descripcion</th>
    <th>Objetivo</th>
    <th>Justificación</th>
    <th>Área de estudio</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td ></td>
    <td >001</td>
    <td >Cultura General.</td> 
    <td >¿Alguna vez has puesto a prueba tu conocimiento sobre el mundo, la historia, las ciencias, el lenguaje y el arte? Tal vez no seas un sabelotodo ni un investigador que pasa sus días en un laboratorio con los ojos pegados a un microscopio, pero hay ciertos datos que deberías conocer para tener una noción del paso del hombre por la Tierra y la complejidad de sus acciones.</td>
    <td>Medir la profundidad de tu cultura general.</td>
    <td>Medir el conocimiento general de la Organización.</td>
    <td>Cultura General.dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd</td>
  </tr>
    
</table>
```

Comment: Gracias Dev. Joel has ayudado mucho... Ajustando algunas cositas pude conseguir algo mas...

Comment: Sí mi respuesta te ayudó a resolver tus dudas. por favor marcarla. Gracias